# Why am I getting a 401 error with specieshindex that involves an API?

Tags: r, http-status-code-401, scopus

I'm having issues with the R package specieshindex https://github.com/jesstytam/specieshindex

I followed the instructions to create an API for Scopus and everything seemed to work okay. But when I try the package functions I get a 401 error:

```
> Count(db = "scopus",
+       search = "t",
+       genus = "Bettongia", species = "penicillata")
Species found on CoL, ITIS, NCBI, or EoL.
Error in Count_f(search = search, genus, species, synonyms, additionalkeywords) : 
  Unauthorized (HTTP 401).
```

If you're trying this, one issue I had during the package installation was around the dependency `rbace` which I had to install from the archive. https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/rbace/

Comment: 401 error mean permission denied. Did you run the `auth()` line in the readme? Did that return something that doesn't look like an error?

Comment: My understanding was that that section referred to a separate database, Web of Science.

Comment: I think you're right. So, just to check, you have an API key configured in the environment variables, and when you run `Sys.getenv("Elsevier_API")` you get that API key back?

Comment: Yep, that works fine. I can see the key when I run that line.